# Error bars and labels are incorrectly positioned in polar coordinate bar graph ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to build a polar coordinate bar graph with error bars and value labels at the end of each bar using ggplot2 in R. I am having a problem where the error bars and value labels are all stacked on top of each other instead of being on the individual bars. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the code and data I used:

```
structure(list(Feature_Set = c("All Features", "Depression Only", 
"Depression + schiz", "Depression + schiz + AD", "Depression + schiz + AD + Cog", 
"Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI", "Cog_BMI_WHR", "cog_and_AD", 
"AD", "Depressive Symptoms", "All Features", "Depression Only", 
"Depression + schiz", "Depression + schiz + AD", "Depression + schiz + AD + Cog", 
"Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI", "Cog_BMI_WHR", "cog_and_AD", 
"AD", "Depressive Symptoms", "All Features", "Depression Only", 
"Depression + schiz", "Depression + schiz + AD", "Depression + schiz + AD + Cog", 
"Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI", "Cog_BMI_WHR", "cog_and_AD", 
"AD", "Depressive Symptoms", "All Features", "Depression Only", 
"Depression + schiz", "Depression + schiz + AD", "Depression + schiz + AD + Cog", 
"Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI", "Cog_BMI_WHR", "cog_and_AD", 
"AD", "Depressive Symptoms"), Trajectory = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Resilient", "chronic", "emergent", 
"depressed improved"), class = "factor"), value = c(65.51, 61.42, 
62, 64.26, 64.99, 65.72, 60.26, 61.6, 59.98, 59.92, 85.13, 69.06, 
72.2, 77.18, 80.61, 83.6, 71.85, 69.72, 66.71, 65.74, 79.5, 66.79, 
70.22, 72.52, 74.87, 77.28, 69.72, 68.17, 63.15, 65.64, 77.39, 
67.97, 69.18, 70.51, 73.08, 75.33, 67.19, 67.82, 68, 65.12), 
    SD = c(3.23, 2.75, 4.01, 3.42, 3.88, 3.23, 3.31, 4.15, 3.34, 
    3.98, 1.57, 2.72, 3.51, 2.53, 2.36, 2.86, 2.51, 3.58, 2.88, 
    1.8, 2.09, 2.44, 2.75, 2.86, 1.98, 1.96, 2.15, 1.88, 2.82, 
    3.87, 1.78, 2.99, 2.71, 3.28, 2.96, 1.53, 2.92, 3.1, 2.76, 
    2.47)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Feature_Set", 
"Trajectory", "value", "SD"))
```

The dataframe (data is below for demonstration purposes).

```
                           Feature_Set         class .    value   SD
1                         All Features          Resilient 65.51 3.23
2                      Depression Only          Resilient 61.42 2.75
3                   Depression + schiz          Resilient 62.00 4.01
4              Depression + schiz + AD          Resilient 64.26 3.42
5        Depression + schiz + AD + Cog          Resilient 64.99 3.88
6  Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI          Resilient 65.72 3.23
7                          Cog_BMI_WHR          Resilient 60.26 3.31
8                           cog_and_AD          Resilient 61.60 4.15
9                                   AD          Resilient 59.98 3.34
10                 Depressive Symptoms          Resilient 59.92 3.98
11                        All Features            chronic 85.13 1.57
12                     Depression Only            chronic 69.06 2.72
13                  Depression + schiz            chronic 72.20 3.51
14             Depression + schiz + AD            chronic 77.18 2.53
15       Depression + schiz + AD + Cog            chronic 80.61 2.36
16 Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI            chronic 83.60 2.86
17                         Cog_BMI_WHR            chronic 71.85 2.51
18                          cog_and_AD            chronic 69.72 3.58
19                                  AD            chronic 66.71 2.88
20                 Depressive Symptoms            chronic 65.74 1.80
21                        All Features           emergent 79.50 2.09
22                     Depression Only           emergent 66.79 2.44
23                  Depression + schiz           emergent 70.22 2.75
24             Depression + schiz + AD           emergent 72.52 2.86
25       Depression + schiz + AD + Cog           emergent 74.87 1.98
26 Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI           emergent 77.28 1.96
27                         Cog_BMI_WHR           emergent 69.72 2.15
28                          cog_and_AD           emergent 68.17 1.88
29                                  AD           emergent 63.15 2.82
30                 Depressive Symptoms           emergent 65.64 3.87
31                        All Features depressed improved 77.39 1.78
32                     Depression Only depressed improved 67.97 2.99
33                  Depression + schiz depressed improved 69.18 2.71
34             Depression + schiz + AD depressed improved 70.51 3.28
35       Depression + schiz + AD + Cog depressed improved 73.08 2.96
36 Depression + schiz + AD + Cog + BMI depressed improved 75.33 1.53
37                         Cog_BMI_WHR depressed improved 67.19 2.92
38                          cog_and_AD depressed improved 67.82 3.10
39                                  AD depressed improved 68.00 2.76
40                 Depressive Symptoms depressed improved 65.12 2.47
```

Code:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=Feature_Set,y=value,fill=Trajectory))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  coord_polar() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:nlevels(data$Trajectory)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = value +20,label = value))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SD, ymax=value+SD), width=.2, position="identity") +
  xlab("Feature Set")+ylab("Predictive Accuracy")
```

Result:

[image]

following the accepted answer, I've updated the code as a example for others with similar problems:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=Feature_Set,y=value,fill=Trajectory))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  coord_polar() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:nlevels(data$Trajectory)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(.9), aes(y = value +10,label = value))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SD, ymax=value+SD), position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  #geom_point(position=position_dodge(.9), aes(y=value, colour=Trajectory)) +
  xlab("Feature Set")+ylab("Predictive Accuracy")
```

[image]

Comment: Please could you paste the results of `dput(data)`. It will make it easier to recreate the data frame; your current example has lots of spaces within columns which we'd need edit out.

Comment: You use `position = "dodge"` in the `geom_bar` but `position = "identity"` in the `geom_errorbar`. Setting `position = "dodge"` inside `geom_errorbar` might solve this.

Comment: @neilfws, thanks for the suggestion. I added the that

Comment: @bVa, I tried that but unfortunately it didn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial solution:

- I removed `width` argument in `geom_errorbar()`
- I prefered using `position = position_dodge()`
- Try different `width` values in `position_dodge()` for the `geom_text` for overlapping text.

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Feature_Set, y = value, fill = Trajectory)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:nlevels(data$Trajectory)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = value + 20, label = value), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - SD, ymax = value + SD), position = position_dodge()) +
  xlab("Feature Set") + ylab("Predictive Accuracy")
```

Comment: Thanks @bVa. I updated my specific code based on your solution as an example for future users.